# TF Timeline shows serial execution despite multithreading settings on Dataset

Tags: io, profiling, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am relatively new to Tensorflow, still struggling to understand how I can improve performance. I used the TF Timeline tool to examine the execution of my code, and I was surprised to see that execution looks like it's serial, as shown in this image below:

[image: screenshot from profiling]

The code below is what I used to set up the data input:

```
filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
dataset   = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, "ZLIB", 128 * 1024 * 1024)
dataset   = dataset.map(_parse_function, 13)
dataset   = dataset.batch(8192)
dataset   = dataset.prefetch(8192 * 3)
iterator  = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
X, y      = iterator.get_next()
```

In particular, given that I have set the number of worker threads on `map` to 13 (consistent with my hardware) and also set a prefetch equal to 3 times batch size, I would have expected the CPU to fully overlap with GPU and CPU/GPU transfer time. So my questions are:

1. Why does this look serial? Am I misreading what I see?
2. Is there something wrong with how I am using Dataset? I understand that batch size & prefetching size should eventually be tuned to get optimal performance, but what's the point if I don't see parallel use of CPU vs. GPU at all?

Comment: I think putting `.prefetch(8192*3)` after `.batch(8192)` is causing it to buffer twenty four thousand batches, or 20 million samples. Try reversing the order so `prefetch` is before `batch` or just `prefetch(3)` batches. That's the way I do it, but I've seen a few questions on here that do it the way you are posting and it's starting to make me second guess myself. So let me know what you find.

Answer (score 4):

The profile looks serial because none of operations in (the parallel invocations of) `_parse_function()` are included in the timeline trace. The `IteratorGetNext` trace region will overlap with some of the operations in the pipeline, but the `dataset.prefetch(8192 * 3)` means that most of the work will be being performed asynchronously in a background thread.

[David Parks' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596718/tf-timeline-shows-serial-execution-despite-multithreading-settings-on-dataset#comment82155169_47596718) makes a good point: a prefetch buffer size of `8192 * 3` *batches* is probably larger than you need, and might be causing memory pressure. Typically setting the prefetch buffer size to a small value (e.g. 1 or 2) is sufficient to overlap preprocessing with training; I would expect diminishing returns soon after that point. Try increasing the `num_parallel_calls` argument to `Dataset.map()` to see if this increases the throughput of your training.